# Firefox plugin to convert POST request to GET?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I heard there was a Firefox plugin called "POST-to-GET" but I can't seem to find it.  It is supposed to intercept a POST request and convert it to a GET request with the parameters appended to the query string.  Does anyone know of a plugin that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/

When you install it in the top bar there will be a menu "Forms" click
it you'll see a dropdown with multiple options go to "Convert Form Methods"
and change accordingly

Comment: yes I believe you can set the content-type header and also you can pass custom headers